# Wrong argument parsing with multithreading - c

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Im working on a project that is mainly producer-consumer with pthread conditions and mutexes on a circular buffer. The user gives how many **consumers** and **producer** threads it wants, **random number generator seed**, how many **numbers** each producer produces and the **size** of the **circular buffer**. All of them along with the condition and the mutex are **global** variables

Here is the producer thread code

```
void * newProducer(void * t){
    // Get the thread id
    int * a = (int *) t;
    int id = *a;
    printf("Producer thread %d started!\n", id);

    int i;
    //Get the seed
    //seed is global vairable(Random number generator seed
    unsigned int thread_seed = seed * id;
    //Allocate memory for the array to save the numbers
    int * numbers = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    //Open the files
    FILE * producer_file = fopen("prods_out.txt", "w");
    if(producer_file == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: fopen failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(producer_file, "-- PRODUCER DATA --\n");

    //Produce the numbers
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++){

        numbers[i] = rand_r(&thread_seed) % 100;

        //Lock mutex
        if(pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: pthread_mutex_lock failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        //printf("Producer thread <%d> locked mutex\n", *id);

        //Wait until the cb has space to store numbers
        while(cb->count == cb->capacity) {
            if(pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex) < 0){
                printf("ERROR: pthread_cond_wait failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("Producer <%d> waiting\n", id);
        }

        //Put the number in the cb
        cb_push_back(cb, &numbers[i]);
       // printf("Producer <%d>: %d\n", id, numbers[i]);
        fprintf(producer_file, "Producer <%d>: %d\n", id, numbers[i]);
        count++;
        //Count is a global variable to inform the consumers that there're 
        //no more numbers to be produced

        //Tell the consumer threads that you have put a number to the cb
        if(pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: pthread_cond_broadcast failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Unlock the mutex
        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: pthread_mutex_unlock failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        //printf("Producer thread <%d> unlocked mutex\n", *id);
    }


    // Free array
    free(numbers);
    //Close File
    fprintf(producer_file, "-- END DATA --");
    if( fclose(producer_file) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: fclose failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //THREAD EXIT
    printf("PRODUCER %d EXITS\n", id);
    pthread_exit(t);
}
```

And here is the consumer thread

```
void * newConsumer(void * t){
    // Get the thread id
    int * a = (int*) t;
    int id = *a;
    printf("Consumer thread %d started!\n", id);
    int  number;

    //Open the file
    FILE * consumer_file = fopen("cons_out.txt", "w");
    if(consumer_file == NULL){
        printf("ERROR: fopen failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(consumer_file, "-- CONSUMER DATA --\n");

    /*Consume integers until there are no integers left
    either to be produced or in the buffer waiting */
    while(count != p*n || cb->count != 0){
        //Lock the mutex
        //printf("Consumer <%d> has locked the mutex\n", *id);
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: Could not lock mutex\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        //Wait until a producer puts an integer in the cb
        while(cb->count == 0 && end == 0){
            printf("Consumer <%d> waiting\n", id);
            if(pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex) < 0){
                printf("ERROR: pthread_cond_wait failed.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        if (cb->count != 0){
            //Consume a number
            cb_pop_front(cb, &number);
           // printf("Consumer <%d>: %d\n", id, number);
            fprintf(consumer_file, "Consumer <%d>: %d\n", id, number);
        }
        //Tell the producers that you have popped a number from the cb
        if(pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: pthread_cond_broadcast() failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        //printf("Consumer <%d> Broadcast.\n", id);

        //Unlock the mutex
        //printf("Consumer <%d> has unlocked the mutex\n", *id);
        if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex) < 0){
            printf("ERROR: pthread_mutex_unlock failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    //Close the file stream
    fprintf(consumer_file, "-- END DATA --");
    if(fclose(consumer_file) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: fclose failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // THREAD EXIT
    printf("CONSUMER %d EXITS\n", id);
    pthread_exit(t);
}
```

In the main function i run

```
pthread_t * CONSUMERS[i] = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * i);
if (CONSUMERS == NULL){
    printf("ERROR: Malloc failed.\n");
    exit(1);
}


for (i = 0; i<c; i++){
    id[i] = i+1;
    pthread_create(&CONSUMERS[i], NULL, newConsumer, &id[i]);
}
```

and the I wait for them to finish.
i do exactly the same for the producer threads.( With a diffrent pthread_t array and id array.)

So the thing is : the id I put at the args at create is getting changed. If I run 5 consumer threads even though I put their id as 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5 it comes out as 65, 2, 3, 4, 68. This happens to the producer threads as well.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Sounds like an alignment issue. Change this `&id[i]` to `(void *)&id[i]` in your pthread creates and see if it helps.

Comment: No, @alvits.  Supposing that a prototype for `pthread_create()` is in scope, conversion of the fourth argument from `int *` to `void *` is implicit and automatic.  Adding an explicit cast perhaps emphasizes that such a conversion happens, but it doesn't change the semantics of the program at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I totally agree _**Supposing** that a prototype for pthread_create() is in scope_. Hence no one has given any answer. We can only guess from the incomplete post and give suggestions.

Comment: My best guess is that something is overwriting elements of the `id` array with different values.  There are numerous ways this could happen, especially, but not exclusively, if that array is global like all your other data.  But it doesn't look like the offending code is among what you presented.

Comment: `pthread_t * CONSUMERS[i]` is utmost suspicious. You end up with the array of pointers, and one element of this array is initialized with `malloc` (whatever `i` happens to be at that time). Then other elements are accessed in the loop. There are UBs all other the place.